# How to unit test a method that contains a database call in Python

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I want to unit test a method that includes a database (SQL Server) call.

I don't want the test to connect to the actual database.

I use unittest for testing, I have done some research and it seems that Mocking could do the trick but not sure about the syntax.

The select statement on the code below returns some integers. I guess that mocking will target the "cursor.execute" and "cursor.fetchall()" parts of the code.

```
from databaselibrary.Db import Db

class RandomClass():

    def __init__(self, database):
        self.database = database # Main DB for inserting data
            
    def check_file_status(self, trimmed_file_data, file_date):
        cursor = self.database.cursor()

        cursor.execute(f"""SELECT DISTINCT query_id
                FROM wordcloud_count
                WHERE date = '{file_date}'""")
        
        queries_in_DB = set(row.query_id for row in cursor.fetchall())

        queries_in_file = set(trimmed_file_data.keys())

        if queries_in_DB == queries_in_file:
            return False
        
        return True
    
    def run(self):
        print("Hello")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    connection_string = 'sql://user:password@server/database'
    
    database = Db(connection_string, autocommit=True)
    
    random = RandomClass(database)
    
    random.run()
```

The test class could look like that:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch
from project.RandomClass import RandomClass
from datetime import datetime

class testRandomClass(unittest.TestCase):
    
    def setUp(self):
        self.test_class = RandomClass("don't want to put actual database here")
    
    @patch("project.RandomClass.check_file_status",return_value={123, 1234})
    def test_check_file_status(self):
        
        keys = {'1234':'2','123':'1','111':'5'}
        
        result = self.test_class.check_file_status(keys, datetime(1900, 1, 1, 23, 59, 59))
        
        self.assertTrue(result)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should mock the db connection object, and the cursor. Then, set the return value of the cursor to return the expected value. I've tested the below code, and used `class Row` to mock the rows returned from `fetchall` call:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
from datetime import datetime
from project.RandomClass import RandomClass


class Row(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.query_id = x


class testRandomClass(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        dbc = MagicMock(name="dbconn")
        cursor = MagicMock(name="cursor")
        cursor.fetchall.return_value = [Row(1), Row(2)]
        dbc.cursor.return_value = cursor
        self.test_class = RandomClass(dbc)

    def test_check_file_status(self):
        keys = {'1234': '2', '123': '1', '111': '5'}

        result = self.test_class.check_file_status(keys, datetime(1900, 1, 1, 23, 59, 59))

        self.assertTrue(result)
```

Since in your RandomClass you iterate rows and get their `query_id`, you need to use a class (or a named tuple) as the row objects returned by the mock.

You should create the row objects you expected, and set them as the return value of fetchall.

Comment: @StamatisTiniakos have you checked my updated answer?

Comment: it looks good. I have just made a small edit to align your code with my example. Happy to approve otherwise.