# Integration tests vs units test on 2 microservices

Tags: testing

Our team designed 2 microservices in 2 distinct GitHub repositories.

- First one is responsible for transforming file inputs to data inserted in a (graph/neo4j) database.
- Second one is a REST API responsible for read-only queries to that database, returning JSONs.

Since these are very **tightly-coupled services** (if the algorithm to populate/update the data in database is wrong, data will be corrupted), my approach was to create units tests on both repos with curated input/expected outputs
i.e. prepared input files to expected nodes, then prepared input nodes to expected JSONs

Is that approach making sense? what about **integration tests** that I suspect to be overlapping in definition here ? are they needed? what would they cover that units tests won't in such scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say these were tightly coupled.  They're both coupled to the database, but that provides a layer of seperation form each other.  Anything which crosses compoenent is a kind of integration test anyway.

In the case of the API, the "real" unit testing approach would be to mock the database calls, so it's not part of the situation.  How straight forward / rebost that is depends on how involved it is.  If that's not practical, restore a test database to a known state before you being.

In the case of file loading the same basic idea applies, although mocking db calls for a data load process is likely to be brittle.  If you use a real database, you'd need to start it from a known state, then validate it's state afterwards.
Question to ask yourself: It is really one operation, or are "parse file" and "write content to db" two units?

Comment: I agree with your first paragraph.

How would you go though for "mocking db call" (in a case of a graph database, or other dbs)? I'm using plain-text cypher queries (similar to sql, for graphs) using the connection from the python client driver, something like graph.run("MATCH .... RETURN n"). 
for the REST Api tests, I was thinking creating queries for insert data (e.g. 'INSERT INTO'/ 'CREATE ... ', here data are nodes and relationships), then triggering the endpoints on the data created on the test graph.

do you mean by "mocking up" writing hard-coded data outside, not touching the db?

Comment: Unfortunately I've no experience with Python, so I can't provide a concrete example. If you have a search around you can probably find some examples.  Maybe something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65931765/how-to-unit-test-a-method-that-contains-a-database-call-in-python